# Playing a mp3 file from the web using VLC in a batch file

Tags: windows, audio, cmd.exe, vlc-media-player

for context im making a USB that rickrolls you in the background (which is why I need cmd) so far the .bat file is :

```
@echo off
vlc --into dummy (the shortened URL is supposed to be here)
```

But I don't know what to add to make it play because I open it and nothing happens any help?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `--into dummy`?

Comment: i dont really know i read that it hides with the expense of a random cmd window

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by switch to VBScript and using this code

```
Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
oPlayer.URL ="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wza1sr5ot55bzdb/rickroll.mp3"
oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
oPlayer.settings.setMode "loop", True
oPlayer.controls.play 
wscript.sleep 212000
```

Feel free to use it this is for a prank.